# Maven repository for java.nio

Tags: file, maven, nio, java-7, java-6

I am writing an application in Java 6 (I have to stick with this).
I need to write a module for file watcher.

After googling around, I found that Java 7 java.nio package is good.
I want to import this sub package alone to maven [my repository] and create the module.

Can any one guide me how can i achieve this? is there any maven repo for such sub-modules?

Comment: In general, you can't easily backport Java standard classes to earlier Java versions. What you need is a file watcher library.

Comment: Yes. badly needed one perfect file watcher library which can inform whenever the file is changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the `java.nio` packages are part of the `rt.jar` of the basic JRE. So they are not present in any other Maven package, since they assume you already have it.

If you want to use NIO from Java 7, you could package and deploy all or part of the `rt.jar` as a Maven module onto your own repo, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this:

```
compile group: 'com.jtransc', name: 'jtransc-rt', version: '0.3.1'
```